# Jewish song book Identity

Tags: jewish-books, books-generally

[image: songbook picture]

I have a song book that I have a screenshot of but have no idea where its from...I reached out to everyone I know...can anyone help?

Comment: Are you looking for the identity of the book, or the song you are pointing at? If the former, what exactly is the problem figuring it out? Does it have a name? An inside cover with the publisher details and whatnot?

Comment: I don't have the actual book just the picture...if I had the book would be pretty easy to find what I need. I love the book so we can sings songs on shabbat/Y"T

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I think I've seen it, I'll as my wife

Comment: Much appreciated! My dad is baal teshuva and would be really helpful and enhance our shabbos table!